# How to cast data in my datatable enumerable?

Tags: c#

**This is my model**

```
public class Data
{
    public string ShipmentNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Tracks> Tracks { get; set; }
}

public class Tracks
{
    public DateTime TrackDatetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrackUTCDatetime { get; set; } 
    public string TrackLocationCode { get; set; } 
    public string TrackEventSID { get; set; } 
    public string TrackEventNotes { get; set; } 
}
```

**I wanted to achieve by casting my datatable values onto the List**

```
List<Data> trackingResponses = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new Data()
    {
        ShipmentNumber = x.Field<string>("ShipmentNumber"),
        Tracks = This is list. So i want to cast my data over here.
    }).ToList()
```

How do I cast the Field into my Tracks which is a list class?

Comment: `Tracks = new List<Tracks>() { new Tracks { TrackDatetime = x.Field<Datetime>("TrackDatetime "), ...  }}` something like that ?

Comment: how does the structure look inside your datatable

Comment: @demo Yes this is the one I was looking for. Thank you so much.